# Google script timestamp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I don't know what the error is.
I have this code and in theory it should work.

```
function timeStamp(e) {

  var sheet = e.source.SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('List');

  var rnge = e.source.getActiveRange();
  var row = rnge.getRowIndex();
  var col = rnge.getColumnIndex();

  var nRnge = sheet.getRange(row, col + 2);
  var dte = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "dd-MM-yyyy");
  nRnge.setValue(dte);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For on edit to work, the function must be named onEdit. Try

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('List');
  var rnge = e.source.getActiveRange();
  var row = rnge.getRowIndex();
  var col = rnge.getColumnIndex();
  var nRnge = sheet.getRange(row, col + 2);
  var dte = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "dd-MM-yyyy");
  nRnge.setValue(dte);
}
```

Comment: Really thank you Nelson!! it's work... mmm and if I have more than one sheet ¿How can I define de event only in sheet "List"?

Comment: if (sheet.getName() == "List") { do what you want here }

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Could you please approve the answer? Thanks.